# Android DatePickerDialog to a year of history

Tags: android, datepicker, history

I'm coding an android app about the egyptian history, and I want to add a DatePicker in a dialog, where I will show years, and whenever the user sets a year, it shows in the layout the events in that year . If he changes the year, the event changes ...etc
It is a historical app, and I don't know how to do it! 
I need help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

You can set min and max date according to the era you want to cover:

```
android:maxDate     The minimal date shown by this calendar view in mm/dd/yyyy format. 
android:minDate     The minimal date shown by this calendar view in mm/dd/yyyy format.
```

And then use the onDateChangedListener to display the correct Layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html

As you want to use only a year, I would advise to use a NumberPickerDialog instead.
DatePicker is maybe "too much" for your use case.